# SQL (PHP MySQLi) Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, create-table

I've exported sql from a MySQL server (version from the exported file says: 5.1.41) and am trying to run the exported sql on a new MySQL server which in the debug says the client version is '5.1.41' but server_info paramater says '5.5.15-log' (I'm using PHP MySQLi extension).

I am getting the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `mojo_global_regions` ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, reg' at line 22
```

And here is the chunk of code it is complaining about:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mojo_global_regions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `region_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `region_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `layout_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `region_id` (`region_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=19 ;
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this syntax?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is `KEY region_id (region_id)`??

Comment: @FahimParkar That creates an index on the field region_id with the name region_id.

Comment: using above query, table is getting created. [see this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/057ca/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a statement before the CREATE TABLE that didn't get terminated properly.

Comment: Took out everything that was before CREATE TABLE and it worked. Thanks! However everything before CREATE TABLE was commented out so not sure unless the comment syntax ("--" end of line comments) was wrong. This is what the MySQL export gave me though but maybe I'm missing something and you cannot run these comments through the PHP mysqli->query method.